# How can I consume a C# Class in node.js?

Tags: c#, javascript, node.js

I have very simple C# code like the following:

```
public class Provider
{
    public IEnumerable<string> GetBundle()
    {
        return new List<string>
        {
            "app/content/css/stylesheet1.css",
            "app/content/css/stylesheet2.css"
        };
    }
}
```

And I need access to these classes from Node.js. What tools are useful for this?

Comment: A better question is "Why are you in this situation in the first place?"

Comment: Is the situation constrained enough that extracting strings ending with ".css" is enough? You probably don't need an entire C# parser.

Comment: I assume you have a raw .cs file, could you just do a regex or loop through lines in the .cs file as you would a normal text file, looking for lines that match .css?

Comment: You could to call a page method through Javascript, as explained at [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: Any reason to not compile that C# to JS using one of the several compilers that do so?

Comment: The regular expression `/"([^"]\.css)"/g` will match anything of the form `"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.css"`

Comment: [edge.js](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge) allows you to run the CLR in a Node process and call into C# code.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the C# to JS using one of the several compilers that do so seems to be the approach I'd use for integrating with node.js.

[Script#](http://scriptsharp.com/), Saltarelle, SharpKit, JSIL are all choices that may apply to your situation and build environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! but it looks like all the tools should be integrated into existing .net project. Such approach doesn't suit me. My case is I know .cs file with a class written in basic C#. My goal is just convert that class to JS function maybe using 3rd party DLLs.

Comment: Looks like you can use a csproj and an msbuild script to generate the JS through script#.... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281781/scriptsharp-compilation-with-nant-script

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297223/use-script-to-compile-code-stand-alone